# Domain specific htpasswd conditions

Tags: .htaccess, dns, .htpasswd

I am using a wildcard dns system that routes all subdomains through a single web app and sets a userid based on the first part of the URL (X.domain.com where X is the username).

I now want to edit my htaccess file to enable conditional httpauth using htpasswd for specific domains. e.g. if url = password.domain.com the enable httpauth.

I'm sure this is possible but have limited knowledge of htaccess.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`SetEnvIf`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_setenvif.html), here's a snippet from [this post](http://tomschlick.com/2009/11/08/conditional-htpasswd-multi-environments/) by Tom Schlick.

```
#allows a single uri through the .htaccess password protection
SetEnvIf Request_URI "/testing_uri$" test_uri

#allows everything if its on a certain host
SetEnvIf HOST "^testing.yoursite.com" testing_url
SetEnvIf HOST "^yoursite.com" live_url
Order Deny,Allow

AuthName "Restricted Area"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /path/to/your/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /
Require valid-user

#Allow valid-user
Deny from all
Allow from env=test_uri
Allow from env=testing_url
Allow from env=live_url
Satisfy any
```

Comment: Note the URL has changed to: http://tomschlick.com/blog/2009/11/conditional-htpasswd-multi-environments.html

Comment: \*Updated answer\* this is why we avoid just posting links. ([How To Answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer))

Comment: Now its actually https://tomschlick.com/2009/11/08/conditional-htpasswd-multi-environments (wihtout a `/` at the end)