# variable path to .htpasswd possible?

Tags: .htaccess, .htpasswd

There is a .htpasswd file in a code base I am working on. The corresponding path to in .htaccess is correct in the production environment but the path does not suit my local environment since the server path is different.

Production: AuthUserFile /var/www/sites/some_dir/.htpasswd

Local Dev: AuthUserFile /path/to/htdocs/some_dir/.htpasswd

Is there a way to make the path to .htpasswd variable, or, if you understand what I am trying to do is there some other way to accomplish this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

We realize that over the Vhost config
dev.domain uses our dev htacces file AuthUserFile /usr/local/www/default.htaccess

For security reasen we generate separate file. Sure you can use the system login for access but we think you open there a door which you can't get safe.

prodution domain uses an other htaccess file

You can generate/update the user in the htaccess by the command

```
htpasswd passwdfile username
```

In our case we type

```
htpasswd /usr/local/www/default.htaccess myusername
```

In the vhost we only set the passwdfile parameter

```
AuthUserFile /usr/local/www/default.htaccess
```

We hope we could help you

Answer (score 0):

Similar to [Domain specific htpasswd conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386182/domain-specific-htpasswd-conditions).

Look at the IfDefine directive for Apache. It lets you define a variable on your production and/or development platform with which you can filter your apache commants. See this link for an example: http://cweiske.de/tagebuch/relative-htpasswd-path.htm.